# Why is QDropEvent::acceptProposedAction() necessary in drag and drop Events?

Tags: c++, qt, drag

I know that we need to accept the proposed action in order to let the widget receive or accept the drop event, but I thought that's what `setAcceptDrops(bool)` do. Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: You don't necessarily want to accept all drag/drop events. You can use this to restrict them based on some conditions you have specified.

Comment: so it is just a way to filter the mimeData it can process?

Comment: Among other things, yes. You can also have other conditions based on which you may not want to accept the drag/drop event. So not only mime data.